# Open Graph Facebook submission

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I make a submission uploading the apk and the simulator build following Facebook's instruction.
My submission has been 3-times rejected with this error:

**General**

- **on iPhone** - Your provided file has been configured incorrectly. Please ensure that you have associated the right credentials for your app and resubmit.
- **on Android** - Your provided file has been configured incorrectly. Please ensure that you have associated the right credentials for your app and resubmit.

I've opened a bug on Facebook platform and the answer has been:
" Please note that you should have received this message from out review team:
"I attempted to download the .apk file by clicking on the provided link on our system. It brought me to a page that said, "invalid Request. I then used the "Save Link As.." option to save and install the .apk to my test phone, but the filed failed to install. I received the following error message: The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error. Check the action's properties and try running the workflow again. Thank you for submitting your app to Facebook."".

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hey, so did you find a solution to this problem ?